# Is there a way to determine the amount of dislocation with transform.Translate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I settled a dash in my game, and I want to happen once the player hits the space button, not while holding it. So I wrote it as `GetButtonDown` to initiate the coroutine, but that makes it so that the player only dashes for a single frame before the `canDash` being settled to false.

I want to know if there is a way to settle the amount of dislocation in the dash in the transform function so that the player can dash all the way with just one click and not having to hold the button.

```
void Update 
{
    direction = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Dash") & canDash == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Dash());
        print("dashing");
    }
}

private IEnumerator Dash()
{
    transform.Translate(direction * dashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    isDashing = true;
    canDash = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashTime);
    isDashing = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashCountdown);
    canDash = true;
}
```

Comment: Well your dash appears to be more a form of teleport. As you just move so far by setting the transform position . It has no speed therefore

Comment: What does deslocation mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are only moving for a single frame because that is exactly what you tell it to do

```
transform.Translate(direction * dashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

is called only exactly once per routine execution.

I think what you rather would want to do is something like e.g.

```
private void Update 
{
    if (!canDash && Input.GetButtonDown("Dash"))
    {
        direction = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

        if(direction != Vector2.zero)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
            print("dashing");
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator Dash()
{
    isDashing = true;
    canDash = false;

    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < dashTime; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        transform.Translate(direction * dashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }

    isDashing = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashCountdown);

    canDash = true;
}
```